# Use of Close in http Request

Tags: http, go, httprequest

what is concurrent relation of Close boolean field in http.Request{} 
What is the impact of setting it to true or false ? Will it hamper concurrent requests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http.Request type is not safe for concurrent use anyway

Setting Request.Close to true or false does not interfere with concurrent requests as your code has undefined behaviour anyway if you use a Request concurrently.